# Formatting PHP include file's resource for use across multiple directory levels

Tags: php, resources, include, filepath

I am attempting to use an include for my footer across all pages on my site.  However, as the pages utilising the footer are spread across a variety of different directory levels the image paths in the footer are not correct for the pages in sub directories (assuming my image path is `src="images/image1.jpg"` and my image folder is in the lowest directory).

I thought about using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and building my image filenames from there but it seems a bit long winded.  Is this the standard way of overcoming this or am I missing something!?

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend consolidating your images in a  single root level directory. If you want to organize them under that then you can add subfolders. If you really need to keep the image sin the individual folders youre including from then you can always symlink those folders into the top level images folder. This way you can always use absolute URLs to reference images, js, css.

The other way would be to write a helper function you can call that will determine the proper path based on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and the path to the file youre including (`realpath(dirname(__FILE__)`). That way you can just call the function instead of reqriting the code to figure it out in every file.

Comment: Cheers,

I am keeping the images all in the same folder but the images in the include have paths that work only when the include is included within a page in the root directory.  All of my admin stuff, for example, is in a subfolder which means that when the include is placed in a page that resides in the admin subdirectory the page looks for the images directory within the admin directory.

Having said that, a quick google search for symlink and that seems to have thrown up some useful ideas.  Perhaps an alias of the image file in the subdirectories may be the best solution?

Comment: No i meant that you shold have a single images folder at the root of the site... not one for each subdirectory (like admin) - this way the path is always the same, ie. `/images/path/to/image.jpg`. What i meant by symlinking is that if for organization purposes you need to have an `images` dir per subdir (like `admin/images`) you could just symlink this folder into `/images`... ie. `ln -s images/admin path/to/admin/images`

Comment: We seem to be talking at crossed purposes what I meant to say was that "the page looks for the images directory within the admin directory - but there is no image directory in the admin directory so no images are displayed".  However - I caught your general idea and symlinking is now working perfectly thanks! :)

Comment: OOOOOH... I see.. sorry about that! Glad you figured it out though